# Could not import utils ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'utils.general'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to run my code and i facing a strange error when i tried to import utils , i have already appended directory using  `sys.path.insert` but still my program is throwing errors

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import argparse
from glob import glob
import os
import sys
sys.path
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/Documents/idr/code')
#import utils.utils as utils 
import utils.general as utils
def get_Ps(cameras,number_of_cameras):
    Ps = []
    for i in range(0, number_of_cameras):
        P = cameras['world_mat_%d' % i][:3, :].astype(np.float64)
        Ps.append(P)
    return np.array(Ps)
```

and the error that i am incurring is

```
import utils.general as utils

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.general'
```

in my utils directory the i have a file with `general.py` but still when i try to import , i am getting an error. please suggest me where i was going wrong.

Comment: Can you write your directory stucture?

Comment: @magicarm22 yes i made sure write permissions for my directory

Comment: Normally this should work. It may be, that you have `utils` library somewhere else, that was e.g. installed as a dependency. Please try to `import utils; print(utils.__file__)` and let us know results.

Comment: also 1 more question - why do you add this library by `sys.path.insert`? Generally you should keep your files in your current working dir and its subdirectories (so using `sys.path.insert` is not needed). Unless you fully know why you keep it outside and add it to sys path.